# How to easily remove Rails engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aop, rails-engines

My hope was, that engines would enable me to easily add or remove features in an app. However, whenever I see how engines are used, noone talks about disabling/uninstalling/unmounting them cleanly. How can I do this?

The case would be a product line of apps that are pretty similar. I would start developing the variant with most features and then work backwards by disabling features to get the other variants of the app.

I would like this to work a bit like aspects in AOP, where I can declare dependencies (in both directions), so that when I want to remove an aspect/engine, all code connected to that engine is removed/disabled. Whenever I try to do this with Rails engines, there has to be a lot of entangled, customized code (e.g. when using parts of the engine in views).

Comment: Do you have an answer fort this now? Also dealing with this issue.

Comment: No answer yet. Somehow this has not been relevant for me anymore.